# Where is this proof wrong (orthogonal projector)?

Tags: linear-algebra

Assume you have a projector $P:V \rightarrow V$, $P^2=P$ and you incorrectly prove the equation which is valid only in the stronger case of an orthogonal projector

$x = Px + (1-P)x$, $\quad \forall x\in V$

by left-multiplying the equation with $P$ and using the idempotence property

$Px = P^2x + Px - P^2x = Px$.

The proof is obviously wrong. I believe the equation is only fulfilled for $x\in$span$(P)$. Where did things go wrong? Asked differently: Where is the orthogonality property needed in the proof of above equation?

Comment: I don't get it. What exactly is wrong? $Px=Px$ as well as $x=Px+(1-P)x$ are both ok for any map $P$, not only for a projection :)

Comment: The equation is only correct in the case of an orthogonal projector. But it seems it can be proofed by just assuming a (possibly oblique) projector.

Comment: $x = Px + (I-P)x$ is true for all $x$ and any map $P:V\to V$.

Comment: The equation $x=Px+(1-P)x$ is true even if $P$ is not a map and the symbols are purely syntactic, given some reasonable axioms such as $1x=x$, $Px-Px=0$ etc

Comment: You don't prove something by assuming it and deriving a tautology, as here $Px = Px$.  And, just as something that irks me, "proof" is a noun; say "prove" when you need the verb, as in "prove the equation".

Comment: You are right! The assumption I made was wrong. I read it on the web and took it for granted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your equation $ x=Px + (1-P)x, \forall x \in V$ holds for all linear functions $P$ ,

$Px + (1-P)x = Px + x -Px= x$

therefore i think your assumption that this holds only for some P is wrong.